# WPF ComboBox KeyUp Event for all comboboxes

Tags: wpf

i have a WPF Application with 50 comboboxes. When i started to write this application a month ago, i forgot to add a KeyUp event to all comboboxes...
Is there a way of adding this event without going to each comboboxes and write xaml code ?

```html
 <ComboBox x:Name="Actif_Vent_CB" Grid.Column="1"
                              SelectionChanged="Actif_Vent_CB_SelectionChanged"
                              KeyUp="Actif_Vent_CB_KeyUp"/>
```

```
 private void Actif_Vent_CB_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            default:
                break;
            case Key.Delete:
            case Key.Back:
                ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

With a Dictionary ?? or something else ??
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse through the layout one by one and check if the element is ComboBox and assign event listeners to them.

Call the following method in the **Loaded** event of your window and pass current window as visual.

```
public void SetEventToComboBox(Visual myVisual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {
            // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

            // Do processing of the child visual object.
            if (childVisual is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)childVisual).KeyUp += Actif_Vent_CB_KeyUp;
            }
            // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
            SetEventToComboBox(childVisual);
        }
    }
```

Source:
[MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0)